# magento 2 Communication link failure:1047 WSREP has not yet prepared

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sql

I am getting a strange error Communication link failure:1047 WSREP has not yet prepared. Can you guys please help me out.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653238/mariadb-galera-error-when-a-node-shutdown-error-1047-wsrep-has-not-yet-prepare

Comment: hi,thanks for sharing but i didn't understood can you please define why the error is?

Comment: Did u solve the issue?

Comment: This issue with the cluster and using Magento support we resolved it.

Comment: I have faced this issue while running the customer script. can you guide to resolve this error.

Comment: Yup we had the same issue and Magento support will take care because it's pure cluster issue and we had no permissions for that.